# DELETE FROM optimization

Tags: sql, optimization, sqlite, sql-delete

I've this query:

```
DELETE FROM f
      WHERE ft != 'f'
         OR fs NOT IN (  SELECT fs
                           FROM f
                       GROUP BY fs
                         HAVING COUNT(fs) >1)
```

It is doing its job nicely except that it takes much more time than I expected. I'm talking about 2.25 secs to down ~209,000 records to ~187,000. I think it could be improved, and I would like to know how.

Query EXPLAIN:

```
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4                 p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -----------------  --  -------------
0     Trace          0     0     0                        00               
1     Goto           0     82    0                        00               
2     Null           0     1     0                        00               
3     String8        0     3     0     f                  00               
4     OpenRead       0     2     0     4                  00               
5     Rewind         0     69    0                        00               
6     Column         0     2     4                        00               
7     Ne             3     66    4     collseq(BINARY)    63               
8     If             7     53    0                        00               
9     Integer        1     7     0                        00               
10    Null           0     6     0                        00               
11    OpenEphemeral  4     1     0     keyinfo(1,BINARY)  00               
12    OpenEphemeral  5     2     0     keyinfo(1,BINARY)  00               
13    Integer        0     11    0                        00               
14    Integer        0     10    0                        00               
15    Gosub          13    50    0                        00               
16    OpenRead       2     2     0     4                  00               
17    Rewind         2     23    0                        00               
18    Column         2     3     16                       00               
19    Sequence       5     17    0                        00               
20    MakeRecord     16    2     4                        00               
21    IdxInsert      5     4     0                        00               
22    Next           2     18    0                        01               
23    Close          2     0     0                        00               
24    Sort           5     53    0                        00               
25    Column         5     0     15                       00               
26    Compare        14    15    1     keyinfo(1,BINARY)  00               
27    Jump           28    32    28                       00               
28    Move           15    14    1                        00               
29    Gosub          12    41    0                        00               
30    IfPos          11    53    0                        00               
31    Gosub          13    50    0                        00               
32    Column         5     0     16                       00               
33    AggStep        0     16    9     count(1)           01               
34    Column         5     0     8                        00               
35    Integer        1     10    0                        00               
36    Next           5     25    0                        00               
37    Gosub          12    41    0                        00               
38    Goto           0     53    0                        00               
39    Integer        1     11    0                        00               
40    Return         12    0     0                        00               
41    IfPos          10    43    0                        00               
42    Return         12    0     0                        00               
43    AggFinal       9     1     0     count(1)           00               
44    Integer        1     4     0                        00               
45    Le             4     42    9                        6a               
46    SCopy          8     18    0                        00               
47    MakeRecord     18    1     4     c                  00               
48    IdxInsert      4     4     0                        00               
49    Return         12    0     0                        00               
50    Null           0     8     0                        00               
51    Null           0     9     0                        00               
52    Return         13    0     0                        00               
53    Column         0     3     4                        00               
54    NotNull        4     57    0                        00               
55    Rewind         4     66    0                        00               
56    Goto           0     68    0                        00               
57    Affinity       4     1     0     c                  00               
58    Found          4     65    4     1                  00               
59    NotNull        6     63    0                        00               
60    Found          4     62    6     1                  00               
61    Integer        -1    6     0                        00               
62    AddImm         6     1     0                        00               
63    If             6     68    0                        00               
64    Goto           0     66    0                        00               
65    Goto           0     68    0                        00               
66    Rowid          0     2     0                        00               
67    RowSetAdd      1     2     0                        00               
68    Next           0     6     0                        01               
69    Close          0     0     0                        00               
70    OpenWrite      0     2     0     4                  00               
71    OpenWrite      1     3     0     keyinfo(1,BINARY)  00               
72    RowSetRead     1     79    2                        00               
73    NotExists      0     78    2                        00               
74    Rowid          0     20    0                        00               
75    Column         0     1     19                       00               
76    IdxDelete      1     19    2                        00               
77    Delete         0     1     0     f                  00               
78    Goto           0     72    0                        00               
79    Close          1     3     0                        00               
80    Close          0     0     0                        00               
81    Halt           0     0     0                        00               
82    Transaction    0     1     0                        00               
83    VerifyCookie   0     2     0                        00               
84    TableLock      0     2     1     f                  00               
85    Goto           0     2     0                        00
```

Table definition (no indexes yet):

```
CREATE TABLE f (fi INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                fn STRING,
                ft STRING,
                fs INTEGER)
```

Comment: Table definitions? Indexes that are defined? Incomplete questions get incomplete answers.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot. I've edited the question. :)

Comment: Another thing worth looking into is the EXPLAIN of the query so the query optimizer tells you what it does with the query. If it does something which is already very clever and fast, there is no reason to optimize further.

Comment: Rather than `ft != 'f'`, can you express the predicate positively like `ft in ('x', 'b')`? I guess it could help the indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that two seconds is a "killer" query (though this, of course, depends on your circumstances and needs) but one thing you *could* test is the effect of splitting the query into two.

That's because it will currently delete records matching either condition so it's an easy transformation into two `delete` statements (within a transaction if you want to ensure it's atomic). You could try:

```
DELETE FROM f WHERE ft != 'f';
DELETE FROM f WHERE fs NOT IN (
    SELECT fs FROM f
    GROUP BY fs
    HAVING COUNT(fs) >1);
```

and see if that improves things. It may or it may not, depending on your DBMS and the makeup of your data. It's likely to get rid of the crossover records (those satisfying both conditions) in the most-likely-faster first query.

But, as with all database optimisations, *measure, don't guess!*

Then you can either recombine and re-evaluate, or concentrate on speeding up the second simpler query if it's still a problem.

One thing to *particularly* make sure of: have indexes on both the `ft` and `fs` columns. That should speed up your queries quite a bit if you don't already have them.

Comment: These indexes did a great job: they cut down the query time by 50%. :)
On the other hand, the query split introduced 10% delay after indexes optimization - SQLite may be optimized enough in this case.
I believe that the indexes gains did the query time become acceptable now.

Thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
DELETE FROM f
WHERE ft <> 'f'
   OR NOT EXISTS (Select * from f f2
       WHERE f2.fs=f.fs and f2.id <> f.id)
```

Indexes

```
on ft ; single-column
on (fs, id) ; composite, in that order
```

Comment: This way the query time was reduced by one-third, not bad. However single indexes reduced it by one-half, which is even better. :)
Thanks anyway for the tip, it's always good to learn different ways of doing the same thing. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE f
FROM (
      SELECT fs 
      FROM f     
      GROUP BY fs     
      HAVING COUNT(fs) <=1
     ) s
WHERE (f.ft != 'f' OR f.fs = s.fs)
```

Comment: Ermm, this syntax `DELETE FROM (...)` apparently isn't supported by SQLite. :(
But thanks anyway dude, it's also a good answer. :)